# Can one appreciate all people without discrimination at all?

Tags: social-ethics

Can one appreciate all people without discrimination at all?

Or is conflict normal? How to deal with it?

Comment: Can someone not discriminate? Yes. Is that normal? Not really. Is conflict normal? Seems pretty common. I don't believe your 2 assertions are opposites so it makes the question a little difficult to answer. And by deal with it, do you mean discrimination or conflict or both?

Comment: @Alex By dealing I mean that how can one avoid conflict, even when it's normal?

Comment: Do you mean conflict in general? If so, then that's probably too broad. If you mean some form of conflict that pertains to discrimination then that may work but I think you'd need to elaborate a bit more.

Comment: Are you referring to discrimination in the most general sense of the word? For example, should I appreciate a mass murderer as much as I appreciate a philanthropist?

Comment: What does 'appreciate' mean here? if you used the word 'love' or 'respect' the question would be more clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

Your question presumes that discrimination and appreciation are mutually exclusive. However, a wine enthusist has a highly discriminant pallet which in large part is due to his great appreciation of wine.